# File read write problem

Tags: c

I wrote the following code.I should change  tags with bill but my code does nothing.What can be the problem?My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;

  char tag [6];
  char code[20]="bill";
  pFile = fopen ("example.asm","r+");
  if (pFile==NULL)
  {
    perror("Error");  
  }
  else
  {

  while(!feof(pFile))
  {
    fgets(tag,5,pFile);

    if((tag=="<bp>") && (!feof(pFile)))
    {

        fputs(code,pFile);  

    }

  }

  }
fclose(pFile);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare strings using the `==` operator since it will compare between two pointers, not the strings they point to, you should use `strcmp(tag,"<bp>")`.

Answer (score 1):

As all people saids in c to comparing strings use `strncmp` or use `pointers`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;

  char tag [6];
  char code[20]="bill";
  pFile = fopen ("example.asm","r+");
  if (pFile==NULL)
  {
    perror("Error");  
  }
  else
  {

  while(!feof(pFile))
  {
    fgets(tag,5,pFile);

    if((strncmp(tag, "<bp>") == 0) && (!feof(pFile)))
    {

        fputs(code,pFile);  

    }

  }

  }
fclose(pFile);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `if (tag == "<bp>")` is not right for C. Try `strcmp` http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strcmp.html

Answer (score 0):

Well at the least you need to change this

```
tag=="<bp>"
```

to this

```
strncmp(tag,"<bp>",4) == 0
```

Comment: It compiles perfectly because `tag` and `"<bp>"` are pointers of the same type, `char *`, thus he is comparing addresses, not the strings.

Comment: @Blag - right.  I haven't run a c compiler in ~10 years, I'm a bit rusty.