# Programming In C and Win32 API: Comparing Strings

Tags: c, string, winapi, comparison, char

I am writing a program in C and Windows API. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express and Character Set is set to "Not Set".  I have made an edit control to accept username. Here's declaration:

```
hwnduser = CreateWindow (TEXT("EDIT"), NULL, 
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
    220, 70, 80, 20,
    hwnd, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL);
```

I am fetching its value into a string named username.

```
len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnduser) + 1;
GetWindowText(hwnduser, username, len);
```

Now, the valid username is in a string called c_user:

```
char c_user[] = "foo";
```

When I compare them to check if the user has entered valid username using following code,

```
if (username == c_user)
{
  MessageBox(hwnd, "Foo", "Bar", MB_OK);
}
else
{
  MessageBox(hwnd, "Bar", "Foo", MB_OK);
}
```

It never validates. Instead, the else condition is always executed! Where am I making a mistake?

How to correct this?

I have tried strcmp! But still, output does not change. See the output(and comparison in code):
[image]

Comment: Have you tried displaying them in a messagebox or comparing lengths?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611250/file-read-write-problem/5611268#comment-6391136

Comment: @krs1 Yep, and I think problem is there. See above. Junk value instead of printing c_user(=foo)

Comment: @Ishan In that case it would be better if you debug why the junk value is being displayed. We are trying to help you with how to compare strings, which wont hold good if you are getting junk values. Thanks for understanding. Put a breakpoint in GetWindowText

Comment: @Sujay Then should I ask this question with different title? I placed breakpoint in GetWindowText but it did not help. The value is correct. The thing is that c_user, to which I have assigned value "foo" is returning junk. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you verify if the window handle is correct. You can cross check with Spy

Comment: OK, I just got the answer. I had assigned values to c_user inside a switch without a case! So, it was never executed! I placed a breakpoint there and it did not work. That rung some bells in head and when I placed declaration outside, it worked beautifully! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ have no built-in string type and so you cannot compare strings this way. C and C++ instead use an array of chars and this syntax simply compares the address of each array (which won't match).

Instead use `strcmp()` or `_tcscmp()`.

Comment: Small correction: in C++, "string type" could be taken as `std::string` or `std::wstring`, which implement `operator==`. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll actually need to use wchar_t's (wide characters).  it's been a while since I've looked at the syntax but i think it'll be something like this:

wchar_t* c_user = L"foo";

if (wcscmp(username, c_user) == 0)
...

make sure username is also defined as the correct type.

you might also look into TCHAR which is a more generic representatic of a character type (it changes based off of the compiler settings).  depending on settings, itll either be a char or wchar_t i think.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `username == c_user` checks whether they both point to the same memory location.
You need to call [`strcmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to compare the strings' values.

Comment: I had tried that. But it does not work. When I tried to print out c_user in message box, it displays a junk value instead! So, problem might be there!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use strcmp (or any synonym)

```
   if ( strcmp( username, c_user) == 0 )
   {
       // 0 indicate there is no difference, thus equal
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use strcmp for this , or strcmpi if you want to ignore the case.

Answer (score 0):

if (strcmp(username, c_user) == 0)
{
...
}

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions GetWindowTextA() and MessageBoxA(), it works for me.