# Spaces are removed from command line arguments when external dll is called from c#

Tags: c#, c++

We've a library written in c which is called by our main application which is written in c# (V 3.5).
Previous version of our c# application was in Delphi and that one was also using the same library.

The usage mode is as follows:

we load the library using `DLLImport` in the c# code and call the required function. That function creates a process using a external dll lying in the library folder and passes path of a text file which will be processed by the external dll.

The problem is that when this process was being done through Delphi application, everything was fine. but, now all the spaces are removed from the path of the text file and it is resulting in "file not found" error from the external dll.

Code in the c file:

```
`Some Work  
  // This routine executes the process  
  if (!CreateProcess (NULL,                 // No module name (use command line).    
                      ProcessCommandLine, // Command line to execute, format : LibraryFolderPath\ExternalLibrary.exe Text File Path\TextFileName.txt  
                      NULL,               //   
                      NULL,               // Thread handle not inheritable.  
                      FALSE,              // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.  
                      0,                  // No creation flags.  
                      NULL,               // Use parent's environment block.  
                      DirPath,            // Use parent's starting directory.  
                      &StartupInfo,       // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.  
                      &ProcessInfo )      // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.  
    )
  {
    // if fails to start application return to caller
    return;
  } // if !CreateProcess
```

The path specified as **"Text File Path\TextFileName.txt"** gets modified as **"TextFilePath\TextFileName.txt"** for the ExternalLibrary.exe

I've tried quoting the path but that didn't help.

Any specific reason for this behavior or any solution??

Comment: I'm a bit confused... where does ProcessCommandLine come from?  Is it built up in the DLL (so shouldn't have changed between C# and delphi version), or is it passed in from the parent application?  If it's the latter, have you checked to make sure the C# code is passing the correct value across to the library?

Comment: @forsvarir The command line is prepared in the c library itself and is same for both delphi and c# applications

Comment: If *all* of the information for the command line is coming from the C library, then it should make no difference what the host application is.  So, if you print out ProcessCommandLine, before the call, you would have: \"LibraryFolderPath\ExternalLibrary.exe\" \"Text File Path\TextFileName.txt\" ?  And this would be the same for both the C# and the Delphi application? And the external dll hasn't changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If lpApplicationName is NULL, the
>   first white space–delimited token of
>   the command line specifies the module
>   name. **If you are using a long file
>   name that contains a space, use quoted
>   strings to indicate where the file
>   name ends and the arguments begin (see
>   the explanation for the
>   lpApplicationName parameter).** If the
>   file name does not contain an
>   extension, .exe is appended.
>   Therefore, if the file name extension
>   is .com, this parameter must include
>   the .com extension. If the file name
>   ends in a period (.) with no
>   extension, or if the file name
>   contains a path, .exe is not appended.
>   If the file name does not contain a
>   directory path, the system searches
>   for the executable file in the
>   following sequence.

I know that you are not working with the above mentioned parameter, but the trick might help.

Comment: @SujoyGhosh As i mentioned in my question, I've tested by using the quoted strings for the library path and path of the text file too. but the results are the same.

Comment: @Bimal - Please add the calling code to the question, as there are some users in SO who post questions - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667651/programming-in-c-and-win32-api-comparing-strings/5667681#5667681) , but the problem does not lie in the posted code. Also mention *exactly where* the value is changing.

Comment: Thank You all for the responses. I figured out the problem. the problem was not with the code but the module being called in the `CreateProcess` argument. it was a Third party library and was very old one. It was not designed to handle spaces in path.